# player's Rect is not aligned with the player/character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I got the bullets to shoot but the player rect is not aligned with the player itself, so the bullets doesn't come from the player but rather from the rect that is offset.

The 3 main Classes:

(bullet, camera and player)

```
def RelRect(char, camera):
    return Rect(char.rect.x - camera.rect.x, char.rect.y - camera.rect.y, char.rect.w, char.rect.h)

class Camera(object):
    '''Class for center screen on the player'''
    def __init__(self, screen, player, levelWidth, levelHeight):
        self.player = player
        self.rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.player.center
        self.worldRect = Rect(0, 0, levelWidth, levelHeight)

    def update(self):
        if self.player.centerx > self.rect.centerx:
            self.rect.centerx = self.player.centerx

        if self.player.centerx < self.rect.centerx:
            self.rect.centerx = self.player.centerx

        if self.player.centery > self.rect.centery:
            self.rect.centery = self.player.centery

        if self.player.centery < self.rect.centery:
            self.rect.centery = self.player.centery


    def draw_sprites(self, surface, sprites):
        for sprite in sprites:
            if sprite.rect.colliderect(self.rect):
                surface.blit(sprite.image, RelRect(sprite, self))
class Bullet():

def __init__(self, x, y, targetX, targetY):
    self.image = ''
    self.origX = x
    self.origY = y
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.targetX = targetX
    self.targetY = targetY
    self.image = image.load('res/attack/attack.png')

    self.vel = 20
    # rnge is the range of the bullet, in frames
    self.rnge = 50
    # prog is the progress of the bullet, in frames
    self.prog = 0
    # dmg is the damage that the bullet will do upon impact
    self.dmg = 1 
    self.dmg_mult = 1
    # deathtick is the timer for enemy death
    self.deathTick = 0
    # rect is the hitbox of the bullet
    self.w, self.h = self.image.get_width(), self.image.get_height()
    self.rect = Rect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)

def update(self):
    # Increases Progress of the bullet
    if not (sqrt((self.targetX - self.origX) ** 2 + (self.targetY - self.origY) ** 2)) == 0:

        self.x += int((self.vel) * (self.targetX - self.origX) /
                      (sqrt((self.targetX - self.origX) ** 2 +
                            (self.targetY - self.origY) ** 2)))
        self.y += int((self.vel) * (self.targetY - self.origY) /
                      (sqrt((self.targetX - self.origX) ** 2 +
                            (self.targetY - self.origY) ** 2)))

    self.rect.center = [self.x, self.y]

def check(self, enemies):
    # Checks if the bullet is out of range, then deletes it, if it is
    if self.prog >= self.rnge:
        bullets.remove(self)
    #checks if bullets are out of bounds
    elif not 0 < self.x < WIDTH - self.w or not 0 < self.y < HEIGHT - self.h:
        bullets.remove(self)

    else:    
        #checks if bullet hits target hitbox, if so, starts a timer that kills the bullet after 1 frame
        for e in enemies:
            if self.rect.colliderect(e.hitbox):
                self.deathTick += 1

        if self.deathTick > 1:
            bullets.remove(self)

#draws each bullet      
def draw(self):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#draws bullet hitboxes
def debug(self):
    draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect, 2)  
    draw.line(screen, (255,255,255), (self.x, self.y), (self.targetX, self.targetY), 4)        

class Player(sprite.Sprite):
    '''class for player and collision'''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.moveUnitsY = 0
        self.moveUnitsX = 0
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ground = False
        self.jump = False
        self.image = image.load("res/move/Ridle.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.Lrun = ["res/move/L1.png",
                 "res/move/L2.png",
                 "res/move/L3.png",
                 "res/move/L4.png",
                 "res/move/L5.png",
                 "res/move/L6.png"]

    self.Rrun = ["res/move/R1.png",
                 "res/move/R2.png",
                 "res/move/R3.png",
                 "res/move/R4.png",
                 "res/move/R5.png",
                 "res/move/R6.png"]

    self.direction = "right"
    self.rect.topleft = [x, y]
    self.frame = 0

def update(self, up, down, left, right):
    if up:
        if self.ground:
            if self.direction == "right":
                self.image = image.load("res/move/Ridle.png")
            self.jump = True
            self.moveUnitsY -= 20
    if down:
        if self.ground and self.direction == "right":
            self.image = image.load("res/move/Ridle.png").convert_alpha()
        if self.ground and self.direction == "left":
            self.image = image.load("res/move/Lidle.png").convert_alpha()

    if not down and self.direction == "right":
            self.image = image.load("res/move/Ridle.png").convert_alpha()

    if not down and self.direction == "left":
        self.image = image.load("res/move/Lidle.png").convert_alpha()

    if left:
        self.direction = "left"
        self.moveUnitsX = -vel
        if self.ground:
            self.frame += 1
            self.image = image.load(self.Lrun[self.frame]).convert_alpha()
            if self.frame == 4: self.frame = 0
        else:
            self.image = self.image = image.load("res/move/Lidle.png").convert_alpha()

    if right:
        self.direction = "right"
        self.moveUnitsX = +vel
        if self.ground:
            self.frame += 1
            self.image = image.load(self.Rrun[self.frame]).convert_alpha()
            if self.frame == 4: self.frame = 0
        else:
            self.image = self.image = image.load("res/move/Ridle.png").convert_alpha()

    if not (left or right):
        self.moveUnitsX = 0
    self.rect.right += self.moveUnitsX

    self.collide(self.moveUnitsX, 0, world)


    if not self.ground:
        self.moveUnitsY += 0.3
        if self.moveUnitsY > 10:
            self.moveUnitsY = 10
        self.rect.top += self.moveUnitsY

    if self.jump:

        self.moveUnitsY += 2
        self.rect.top += self.moveUnitsY
        if self.ground == True:
            self.jump = False

    self.ground = False
    self.collide(0, self.moveUnitsY, world)


def collide(self, moveUnitsX, moveUnitsY, world):
    self.ground = False
    for pos in world:
        if self.rect.colliderect(pos):
            if moveUnitsX > 0:
                self.rect.right = pos.rect.left
            if moveUnitsX < 0:
                self.rect.left = pos.rect.right
            if moveUnitsY > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = pos.rect.top
                self.moveUnitsY = 0
                self.ground = True
            if moveUnitsY < 0:
                self.rect.top = pos.rect.bottom
                self.moveUnitsY = 0
```

and then the running loop:

```
while running:
    for evnt in event.get():
        if evnt.type == QUIT or evnt.type == KEYDOWN and evnt.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

        if evnt.type == KEYDOWN and evnt.key == K_UP:
            up = True
        if evnt.type == KEYDOWN and evnt.key == K_DOWN:
            down = True
        if evnt.type == KEYDOWN and evnt.key == K_LEFT:
            left = True
        if evnt.type == KEYDOWN and evnt.key == K_RIGHT:
            right = True

        if evnt .type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # checks if any mouse button is down,  if so sets clicking to true
            button = evnt.button
        #startTicks = time.get_ticks()            
        if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            # checks if any mouse button is down,  if so sets clicking to true
            button = 0       
        if evnt.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            # sets mx and my to mouse x backgand y if mouse is moving
            mx, my  = evnt.pos        

        if evnt.type == KEYUP and evnt.key == K_UP:
            up = False
        if evnt.type == KEYUP and evnt.key == K_DOWN:
            down = False
        if evnt.type == KEYUP and evnt.key == K_LEFT:
            left = False
        if evnt.type == KEYUP and evnt.key == K_RIGHT:
            right = False

    if button == 1:
        bullets.append(Bullet(player.rect[0]+ player.rect[2]//2, player.rect[1] + player.rect[3]//2, mx, my))




    asize = ((screen_rect.w // background_rect.w + 1) * background_rect.w, (screen_rect.h // background_rect.h + 1) * background_rect.h)
    bg = Surface(asize)

    for x in range(0, asize[0], background_rect.w):
        for y in range(0, asize[1], background_rect.h):
            screen.blit(background, (x, y))

    for b in bullets:
        b.update()
        b.draw()
        b.check(enemies)    

    time_spent = sec(clock, FPS)
    camera.draw_sprites(screen, all_sprite)

    draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), player.rect, 4)

    player.update(up, down, left, right)
    camera.update()
    display.flip()
```

if you run the program itself, you can see that the red rectangle (4th last line) that represents the player rect is not to where the character is suppose to appear....

How can I make it so that the player rect will be at the position of the character? So that the bullets come from the player.

Thanks :)

Full Code Here:
https://pastebin.com/z1LwxYYt

Comment: That's too much code for Stack Overflow. Please [reduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I made it shorter a bit taking out the levels and only showing the main 3 intertwining classes, the camera, player and bullet classes. Along with the running loop. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that neither your red rectangle nor the bullets are drawn to the screen in relation to the camera.

The `Bullet` class should subclass `Sprite`, too, so you can add them to the `all_sprite`-group, like you do with the obstacles and the player.

Then let the `Camera`-class handle the drawing of the bullets.

As for the red rectangle, I suggest removing the `RelRect` function and move it into the Camera class itself, like this:

```
class Camera(object):
    ...
    def translate(self, rect):
        return Rect(rect.x - self.rect.x, rect.y - self.rect.y, rect.w, rect.h)

    def draw_sprites(self, surface, sprites):
        for sprite in sprites:
            if sprite.rect.colliderect(self.rect):
                surface.blit(sprite.image, self.translate(sprite.rect, self))
```

which would allow you to draw the rect like this:

```
draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), camera.translate(player.rect), 4)
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that the bullet rect had to be relative to the camera hahaha.